# angular-material: how to control the position of the active highlight color bar

Tags: angular

In my Angular 7 application, I'm using `tab` component from angular material. I just follow the basic usage:

```
<mat-tab-group id="tab-group">
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

But in my case, the UI goes as following:

[image]

The highlight color bar for the active tab is on the top, which is different from the demo. How so

Comment: Did you import theme ? You have in styles.scss file `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';` ?

Answer (score 1):

Include one of `Angular Material's` pre-built `themes` globally in your application.
In your `styles.css`

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```